# GoogleDrive file multipart type upload in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, google-drive-api, xamarin.forms

My Xamarin forms application uploads a zip file to google drive using rest apis.But the name is always displaying as "untitled".So I tried using multipart content,but got the parse error with "code": 400,

```
var jsonstring = "{ \"name\": \"demo.zip\” }";

var multicontent = new MultipartContent();

var strcontent = new StringContent(jsonstring);

var backupContent = “byte array content of my file”;

multicontent.Add(strcontent);
multicontent.Add(backupContent);
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer”, “my token value");

HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Length", backupContent.ContentLength.ToString());

   HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/related");

var res = await HttpClient.PostAsync( "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart", multicontent);

var stringContent = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: 400 means your request is malformed. Check out the google drive documentation and make sure you are formatting correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Google Drive [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#400_bad_request), The error `400: Bad Request` that you got is a user error. This error is caused by:

- required field or parameter has not been provided
- the combination of provided fields is invalid
- the value supplied in the parameter is invalid

Another caused of this error is when trying to add a duplicate parent to a Drive item. It can also be thrown when trying to add a parent that would create a cycle in the directory graph.

For more information, check this [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) to know the different upload options that you can do in Google Drive API. You can also check this [ZIP Extractor](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/examples/) if it can help you.